# If God does not like dogs to be kept as pets, why is it not in the Quran? Is the hadith about dogs untrue?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, dogs

Please I need some clarification.  If God does not like dogs to be kept as pets, why did he create them to be loving and caring?  Why is it not in the Quran that having a dog pet is Haram?

I learnt a prostitute woman gave water to a starving dog and God forgave her sins and she went to heaven:

> Allah's Messenger said, "A prostitute was forgiven by Allah, because, passing by a panting dog near a well and seeing that the dog was about to die of thirst, she took off her shoe, and tying it with her head-cover she drew out some water for it. So, Allah forgave her because of that." ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/127))

It says in the Quran:

> It is We who relate to you, [O Muhammad], their story in truth. Indeed, they were youths who believed in their Lord, ...
>
> We would have certainly spoken, then, an excessive transgression.  These, our people, have taken besides Him deities.  ...
>
> He whom Allah guides is the [rightly] guided, but he whom He leaves astray - never will you find for him a protecting guide. And you would think them awake, while they were asleep. **And We turned them to the right and to the left, while their dog stretched his forelegs at the entrance.** If you had looked at them, you would have turned from them in flight and been filled by them with terror. -- [Qur'an 18:13-18](https://quran.com/18:13)

The dwellers of the cave were with their dog. God called them "true muslims" (surah Kahf).

It says only in the hadith that a dog pet is not allowed in Islam.  E.g.

> The Prophet said, "Whoever keeps a (pet) dog which is neither a watch dog nor a hunting dog, will get a daily deduction of two Qirat from his good deeds." ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/6))

My Imam told me anything that contradicts what the Quran says is untrue.
Therefore, is that hadith about dogs untrue?  Because it clearly contradicts the Quran.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] and [meta] to learn more about this site.

Comment: You should believe both (but Quran in first place, then Sunnah or Hadith) and if possible check our site see for examples all answers here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs if they still don't give a clue you can edit your question and focus it to the points which are not already answered elsewhere (see also [ask]). The point with dogs is that it is allowed to have dogs as a useful help like hunting or as a help for sheepherder. The dwellers of the cave were such people.

Comment: Dogs can be held for the purposes Medi1Saif mentioned above, but they can't be kept as pets inside home for they bear impurities that are harmful for us spiritually or physically or both. One should also purify his body and clothes for performing religious rituals if s/he touches them. So it is right to keep them but one should stay clean from their impurity.

Answer (score 5):

### The test

Allah created this world in such a way to serve the purpose of testing people, he says:

> [He] who created death and life to test you [as to] which of you is
>   best in deed - and He is the Exalted in Might, the Forgiving -
>   67:2

And:

> Do the people think that they will be left to say, "We believe" and
>   they will not be tried? But We have certainly tried those before them,
>   and Allah will surely make evident those who are truthful, and He will
>   surely make evident the liars. 29:2

Most of the things which are **forbidden has good sides** such as **dogs**, they **are friendly, loyal and helpful**.

Think about similar things, Islam **prohibited** some of the things **completely**, such as drinking and having affairs, and some are allowed within **limited scope** such as dogs (for guarding and hunting) and marriage (limited number, cannot marry some relatives). Allah created life this way so people are distinct, some will follow Allah’s will and some will find excuses for themselves to ignore his will.

### The prostitute

Allah forgave her sins because she saved a soul, and did not neglect it, regardless it was a dog or not so it does not support your question.

### Ahl Al-Kahf (the cave)

The dog was not in the cave:

> And We turned them to the right and to the left, while their dog
>   stretched his forelegs at the entrance. 18:18

And even if it was there, every nation had different Sharia, we cannot question Allah why allowed things for some nation or forbidden them to another, for example, statues where allowed for prophet Soliman, but it’s not allowed in Islam

Imam Qurtubi said in his Tafsir: most commentators see that it was a real dog belongs to one of them for hunting, or for his sheep.

### Hadith indeed is from Allah.

Hadith is from Allah as quran, but with words from the prophet, it’s not his own philosophy, it’s all from Allah 
Quran says:

> Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination. It is not but a
>   revelation revealed,……..53:3-4

And the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "***Beware! I have been given the Qur'an and something like it***" which is (Sunnah including Hadith) and he warned us from those who say if you don’t find it in Quran then it’s untrue, many rules are mentioned only or explained in Sunnah (such as prayer details can you find it in Quran!?), and Muslims who do not accept them, are like disbelieving the Prophet.

> Narrated Al-Miqdam ibn Ma'dikarib: The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Beware! I
>   have been given the Qur'an and something like it, yet the time is
>   coming when a man replete on his couch will say: Keep to the Qur'an;
>   what you find in it to be permissible treat as permissible, and what
>   you find in it to be prohibited treat as prohibited. Beware! The
>   domestic ass, beasts of prey with fangs, a find belonging to
>   confederate, unless its owner does not want it, are not permissible to
>   you If anyone comes to some people, they must entertain him, but if
>   they do not, he has a right to mulct them to an amount equivalent to
>   his entertainment.
>
> [Sahih (Al-Albani)](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/9)

### No contradiction

The Hadith you mentioned does not contradict with Quran, where do you find in Quran that dogs are permissible as pets!? There is no such thing, on the other hand Allah says:

> And whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has
>   forbidden you - refrain from. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe
>   in penalty. 59:7

The Prophet was sent to guide us, your emotions may mislead you, the prophet knows better, so do not give up your faith for such ideas or feelings.

Comment: I like this answer especially the explanation about the hadith about the prostitute. However i'm sure that this question or the questions of OP have been covered several times on ths site. So with a little searching effort he would have found his answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm sure he can find the information, maybe in multiple questions, you see this one is like four questions together.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is strongly misunderstood.

If you translate the Arabic text and pay attention to the word roots, it says smth like "cattle dog" but does not literally say "hunting", rather smth inbetween hunting/guarding.

And another, much more important point. There's another Hadith saying to not eat animals having fangs.

I think these Hadiths are connected by meaning. It's just this: dogs are to be kept as servants (not restricted by just hunting and herding) but NOT as food. Simple as that.